# View source of PHP, Javascript, and HTML?

Tags: php, javascript, html, pretty-print

I've got a .php file with javascript, php, and html.  I want to include a button/link to view the source of the entire file "pretty printed", but I can't seem to get anything to work.  What is the best way to do this?

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3793145/html5-tag-to-display-syntax-highlighting/3793175#3793175

Answer (score 3):

Some combinations of Apache/PHP are configured so that files ending in `.phps` aren't run as PHP, but instead, highlighted and prettified.

Example:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

If you simply want to display the code of the file, you can call this function:

```
function echoFile($pathToFile){

  $handle   = fopen($pathToFile, "r");
  $contents = fread($handle, filesize($pathToFile));
  fclose($handle);
  $contents = str_replace("<", "&lt;", $contents);
  $contents = str_replace(">", "&gt;", $contents);
  echo "<pre>$contents</pre>";
}
```

So, if you want to display myPhpFile.php, just do

```
echoFile("myPhpFile.php");
```

As far as making it prettified, follow the link that was commented.

Comment: I'd recommend also replacing `&` with `&amp;` to avoid the character being parsed as an entity. Also, do this before replacing `<` and `>` to avoid re-escaping the escaped angle brackets.