# In my HTML and CSS documents, how can I highlight the syntax of code snippets?

Tags: html, css, syntax-highlighting

I recently started to learn HTML and CSS.

When I use `<code></code>`, it just shows up as plain, black and white text, although I would like it to automatically highlight the syntax appropriately.

It currently looks like this:

```
text = "Hello World!"
print(text)
```

I would like it to look like this:

```py
text = "Hello World!"
print(text)
```

Is it possible to do that with just HTML and CSS?

Comment: Also keep in mind I cannot currently post screenshots, as I am new here.

Comment: Do you make some search before asking?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [HTML5 tag to display syntax highlighting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3793145/html5-tag-to-display-syntax-highlighting)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> automatically highlight

> Is it possible to do that with just HTML and CSS?

No.

---

It requires more detailed markup and CSS.

e.g.

```css
var {
  color: blue;
}

code.operator {
  color: red;
}

code.literal {
  color: purple;
}

code.function-call {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<pre><code class="python"><var>text</var> <code class="operator">=</code> <code class="literal">"Hello World!"</code>
<code class="function-call">print(<var>text</var>)</code>
```

---

To do it *automatically* you need to involve a programming language. You could use it to preprocess your code before it is delivered to the browser, or use client-side JavaScript to do it after the page has loaded.

There are [various libraries](https://duckduckgo.com/?hps=1&q=javascript%20dom%20syntax%20highlighter%20library&atb=v376-1&ia=web) available to to this.

Comment: Ah I see. I need to do it by hand or involve JavaScript. Thank you for the answer!

Answer (score 0):

For syntax highlighting, you typically need to use additional tools or libraries. One common approach is to use JavaScript-based syntax highlighting libraries like "highlight.js" or "Prism.js." These libraries can dynamically apply appropriate styles to different parts of the code to make it visually appealing and easy to read.